# What is the best way to deal with dialogs in a ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

**Following-up on the IDialogService approach:**

What about the `System.Windows.MessageBoxResult` enum? Is the better approach to keep it out of the interface and only involve it in the implementation?

**Approach I chose for the `System.Windows.MessageBoxResult` enum**:

I added an enum next to the IDialogInterface that covers Yes, NO, Ok, Cancel:

```
namespace Foo.Bar.Dialogs
{
    public enum DialogResult { Ok, Yes, No, Cancel }

    public interface IDialogService
    {
        void ShowErrorBox(string error_message);

        DialogResult ShowQuestionBox(string question_message);

        DialogResult ShowQuestionBox(string question_message, string caption);

        DialogResult ShowQuestionBox(string question_message, string caption, bool allow_cancel);

        DialogResult ShowQuestionBox(string question_message, string caption, bool allow_cancel, bool show_as_error);

        void ShowWarningBox(string message, string caption = "");

        void ShowInformationBox(string message);

        void ShowInformationBox(string message, string caption);
    }
}
```

**Initial question:**

I am working on moving all the commands from my .asmx.cs file to the ViewModel of the main window of some application.

Now I have to figure out what to do with commands that ask for confirmation(s) from the user.

*For now* I'll just suck in the necessary types in my ViewModel to launch my dialog boxes directly. I'm pretty sure this is not the best or *cleanest* way to do this.

I found this [article](http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2010/07/25/mvvm-and-confirmation-dialogs.aspx) with an interesting and cleaner approach. It uses an IDialogService interface:

```
public interface IDialogService
{
    int Width { get; set; }
    int Height { get; set; }
    void Show(string title, string message, Action<DialogResult> onClosedCallback);
}
```

I also found this [article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-implement-MVVM-71a65441) which seems even better as it checks if the IDialogInterface is null before trying to use it:

```
private void PerformAddNewCustomer() 
{ 
    CustomerList.Add(new Customer { Name = "Name" + i }); 
    i++; 

    if (dialogService != null) 
    { 
        dialogService.Show("Customed added"); 
    } 
}
```

Is this the best way to separate dialogs from the ViewModel, or is there an even better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the approach in the link you posted is a good one and also very widespread (source: me looking at code on the web ;) ). It's rather simple to use, it makes dialogs testable by using a dummy service in your unit tests and it simplifies the process of refactoring your dialogs.

Personally, my `DialogService` method signature takes a list of `Tuple<string, Action>` and I create my dialog window's buttons based on that. It allows the `ViewModel` to request for some special functions from the dialog windows without having to add new methods to my service every time my needs are more than an `Ok` or `YesNo` message box (while I do have those as methods on their own for ease of use).

So it's a solid approach and at this point I don't think you will find something that is flat out better, only something you might like more personally.

Answer (score 0):

The article you found is a good approach to deal with dialog windows in MVVM and it is really reusable and with the DI it is easy to use in your views.

I did use something different, most of the time i use MVVM light toolkit and it has a messenger and i used the messenger to send a message to a separated class and then it opened for me the dialog i wanted to show, and the result is messaged back so i can act to the users choice.